# Click event not firing on a div containing overlaid images in Firefox

Tags: firefox, jquery

I'm trying to show a popup when someone clicks on a youtube thumbnail. This works fine in Chrome but the click event isn't firing in Firefox.

I've managed to cut the problem down to what I've got below ([Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/xehB2/4/))

```
<div class="Youtube">
    <img class="Thumb" src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/RsYlGFBEpM4/mqdefault.jpg" alt="Marrakech"/>
    <img class="PlayButton" src="http://ec2-54-229-110-227.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/Content/images/VideoPlay.png" alt="Play button"/>
</div>
```

The attach is happening fine but the handler doesn't get called in Firefox

```
$(".Youtube").click(function () {
    alert('clicked');
    return false;
});
```

I suspect it's something to do with the positioning/layout of the div or images

```
.Youtube
{
    margin: 5px;
    width: 320px;
    height: 180px;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: solid 5px #f00;
    position: relative;
}

div.Youtube img.Thumb {
    position:relative;
    z-index:-1;
}

.Youtube img.PlayButton {
    height: auto;
    width: 160px;
    position:relative;
    left:20px;
    top:-160px;
    z-index:-1;
    opacity: .7;
}
```

Can someone point out my mistake? (I've just noticed the *border* of the div catches clicks are appropriate, just not any content)

Comment: Using a positive z-index works: see [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/masteram/SbcXg/). Do you have to use negative values?

Comment: With a positive zindex; something like this in firefox http://jsfiddle.net/xehB2/7/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a positive z-index set on `.Youtube` class works fine on FF too.

Code:

```
.Youtube
{
    margin: 5px;
    width: 320px;
    height: 180px;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: solid 5px #f00;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

I'm searching for the reason on the net...

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/6Zkua/

### EDIT

I think the reason why is that we are defining all the elements in the same stacking context `relative`, but firefox in this context assume `undefined` if the z-index is not set so the element will be always at lower index.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context

Comment: I'd be interested to know the reason if you can find one

Comment: @Basic added explanation, I think

Answer (score 2):

Try : [This updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xehB2/9/) - removed superfluous use of z-index property.

```
.Youtube
{
    margin: 5px;
    width: 320px;
    height: 180px;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: solid 5px #f00;
    position: relative;
 }

div.Youtube img.Thumb {
    position:relative;
}

.Youtube img.PlayButton {
    height: auto;
    width: 160px;
    position:relative;
    left:20px;
    top:-160px;
    opacity: .7;
}
```

Comment: Not actually superfluous as it's there to avoid issues with some other content but I can work around that. +1 but I've marked @Edward's as correct since he beat you to it slightly. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Explicitly adding z-index to Div makes it work on firefox

```
z-index:0
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LsqAq/3/